# --javascript-delay for doing a screenshot using imgkit and Python

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, imgkit

Using Python, imgkit and wkhtmltopdf (2.0) library I'm trying to make a screenshoot for the whole page. After some preparation I'm calling a method make_screenshot:

```
def make_screenshot(url):
   options = {
    'format': 'png',
    'javascript-delay': '2000',
}

return imgkit.from_url(url, False, options=options)
```

But when it runs I'm obtaining an error like this:

```
Loading page (1/2)
Rendering (2/2)                                                    
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Done
```

Screenshot, which is created, shows that page isn't fully loaded. How to resolve it?